# Proper Mathematical Typesetting for a point?

Tags: math-mode, geometry

I'm working on a document in LaTeX, and I was wondering what the proper typsetting for a point is?  If my understanding is correct, bold capital letters are matrices, vectors have the \vec{} symbol above them, well known sets use that fancy font thing, but what do you do when specifying a point (in multidimensional space)?  Is there a special symbol for it?  Is it just a bold lower case letter?

I didn't see anything about points in the LaTeX math guide, does anyone know of a good resource in case I come across something like this again?

Comment: There is no rule. Usually I use simple capital letters `$P$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You can always wrap it in a dummy command (perhaps `\pt`?)—that way you can change the format later if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a standard:

The standard DIN-EN-ISO-80000-2 chapter 8 uses roman uppercase letters. The given examples look like in my MWE. 
In every case, you should define a macro `\newcommand{\point}[1]{\whateveryoulike{#1}}` in order to have it semantically nice coded and to be able to change it afterwards. If you choose some other style later, you may change the whole document in a second.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\point}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\point{AB}\parallel\point{CD}$\\
$\point{AB}\perp\point{CD}$\\
$\sphericalangle{}\point{ABC}$\\
$\overline{\point{AB}}$\\
$d(\point{A},\point{B})$
\end{document}
```

[image]